# confused about why UDP client server is doing this

Tags: java, udp, udpclient

Im creating a client-server application using UDP. Before anyone asks why I'm using UDP instead of TCP let me tell answer by stating that its for an assignment. Ok on to the question!

I have created a client class that spawns a thread in order to send packets to the UDP server. The main thread listens for the packets coming in. The server class acts as a welcome message pushing service as well as middle man for passing the messages of the clients to everyone.

When I created two clients the first clients output goes like this:

```
Please enter your name for the server: 
James
Welcome to the server James
Hi all // User james types this
James: Hi all // Outputs his message to him once - that's fine
Hi mate // Output from another user
```

This is how I want all the clients to send and receive messages. But when the second client does the same I get the following output:

```
Please enter your name for the server: 
Owen
Welcome to the server Owen
Hi all         // Client one (James wrote this)
Hi mate
Owen: Hi mate
Hi mate
```

Notice that I have received the same message twice here but on the first client I only receive it once. Here is my logic in the server class for sending messages to the client:

```
// Get the response
                String response = new String(packet.getData());

                // Test - send a message from the server to each user
                if( ports.size() > 1 )
                {
                    for( int i = 0; i < ports.size(); i++ )
                    {
                        System.out.println( "Values in port arraylist: "+ports );

                        if( packet.getPort() == ports.get(i) )
                        {

                        } else 
                        {
                            // String toSend = names.get(i).concat( ": "+response );
                            // System.out.println( toSend );
                            buf = response.getBytes();

                            System.out.println( "Packet Receieved from Port: "+packet.getPort()+"\nPorts.get: "+ports.get(i) );

                            // Could store all address in own arraylist for outside local host networking
                            int thisPort = ports.get(i);
                            packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length,packet.getAddress(),thisPort );
                            socket.send(packet);
                            System.out.println( "Sending message to port "+ports.get(i) );
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println( "\n" );
                    packet = null;
                }
```

To test this I added some output lines to see what was going on up here and got this:

```
Values in port arraylist: [61493, 61494]
Values in port arraylist: [61493, 61494]
Packet Receieved from Port: 61493
Ports.get: 61494
Sending message to port 61494


Values in port arraylist: [61493, 61494]
Packet Receieved from Port: 61494
Ports.get: 61493
Sending message to port 61493
Values in port arraylist: [61493, 61494]
Packet Receieved from Port: 61493
Ports.get: 61494
Sending message to port 61494
```

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you should add the homework tag!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it was doing this but I fixed it by placing a global variable in the code to hold the temp value of the port for comparison :/